Some confusion about the 245th page of Hamilton's The Ricci flow on surfaces
When I read the Hamilton's The Ricci flow on surfaces (237- 262 of this). I fail to get the (2) from (1) in picture below, where the $T$ of (1) is any nonnegative real number. In fact, I feel it is wrong. Since in yesterday, I ask a problem  using my own words, people seem to think it's not right (in fact, I also think).
The author's aim is to get (4). On the one hand, (2) is not necessarily true. On the other hand, I can't see how to get (4) from (2) (3).  I can't understand the mean of "the integral is frequently small" which is above (4).
Thanks for any help.
What I try(2024-9-3): I know how to get (2) from (1). In fact, the constant $C$ of (1) (2) are different.




"the integral is frequently small" should mean (2). In fact, from (2) and (3), we have (4),  since the $t$ of (4) can't be far from the $t$ of (2).
